Could not create 'wp-config.php' file with `wp-cli`
I am trying to install Wordpress in my container, and configure it so it can connect to mysql database, and I want to do this using only wp-cli, I know the manual way.
Here is the Dockerfile that I am using for testing purpose :
Dockerfile:
FROM mariadb:10.11.5

RUN apt update && apt install curl php php-fpm php-mysqli php-phar -y
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html
RUN curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar
RUN chmod +x wp-cli.phar
RUN cp wp-cli.phar /usr/local/bin/wp

and here is how to build it and run it :
docker build . -t wp-test
docker run -d --name wp-test-container --env MARIADB_USER=tofa7a --env MARIADB_PASSWORD=1337 --env MARIADB_DATABASE=wordpress --env MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=42 wp-test

the container is running in a detachable way now, we need to access it using the following command :
docker exec -it wp-test-container bash

then I install wordpress using the wp-cli :
wp core download --path="/var/www/html" --allow-root

and when I try to run the following command which is has to create for me the wp-config.php that will contain the mysql database informations, it gives me the error below, and creates the file empty
wp config create --dbname=wordpress --dbuser=tofa7a --dbpass=1337 --path="/var/www/html" --allow-root

PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/templates/phar://usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/config-command/templates/wp-config.mustache): Failed to open stream: phar error: "vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/templates/phar:/usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/config-command/templates/wp-config.mustache" is not a file in phar "wp-cli.phar" in phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/utils.php on line 608
Error: Could not create new 'wp-config.php' file.

the weird thing is when I try and run it within the wordpress path it works :/
firstly let's delete the empty wp-config.php file, so wp-cli won't complain about an existing file.
rm /var/www/html/wp-config.php

and then let's change the directory to the wordpress content path :
cd /var/www/html/
wp config create --dbname=wordpress --dbuser=tofa7a --dbpass=1337 --allow-root

the file has created successfully :
Success: Generated 'wp-config.php' file.

it also works by running the wp-cli.phar directly, which I download it previously in the dockerfile steps, you will find it in the root path / :
rm /var/www/html/wp-config.php
cd /
./wp-cli.phar config create --dbname=wordpress --dbuser=tofa7a --dbpass=1337 --path="/var/www/html" --allow-root

again the file has created successfully :
Success: Generated 'wp-config.php' file.

is there a way to make wp-cli work without those illogical workarounds, am I missing something, I think it has to be something about permissions.

Why do you start with a database container and install PHP in it? Why not use a PHP container besides the first one instead?

@NicoHaase I do have another setup where I separate each service in its own container, but just for the example purpose I did it in one container, to facilitate the process for viewers who want to test the behavior.

It seems as if WP_CLI_ROOT has been set incorrectly (either implicitly or explicitly). The URI should read phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/ (three slashes) instead of phar://usr/local/bin/wp/ (two slahes) when trying to load the template...
